# Can I automatically export the Excel file for the Site Usage Report daily?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerbi

In my SharePoint site there is an option to "Download 90 day site usage data"  and I would like to be able to do this automatically every day.  My end goal is to use this data to make my own report in Power BI that is structured a little differently than the built in SharePoint one.

Is there any way for me to get this to download automatically every day weather using Power Automate or some other resource?  Any Suggestions or help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, you can try to use [PowerShell and Graph](https://office365itpros.com/2020/05/07/reporting-sharepoint-online-site-usage-data-powershell-graph/) to get the usage report. And Azure Automation shall provide you the option to [schedule the PowerShell script](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/learn/automation-tutorial-runbook-textual-powershell).